# How can I get list of only running instances when using ec2-describe-tags

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

How can I get list of only running instances when using `ec2-describe-tags`. I am using my command like this:

```
ec2-describe-tags --filter "resource-type=instance" --filter "value=somevalue" --filter "key=key"
```

Comment: Are you attempting to use the AWS CLI in PowerShell? You may want to take a look at [AWS Tools for PowerShell](https://aws.amazon.com/powershell/) instead.

Comment: No I am on mac and just using ec2 command line tools

Comment: I'll retag your question to help you find the right audience, then.  The aws-powershell tag is for a Windows module... probably won't find much mac help there. :)

Answer (score 67):

It is easy using the [aws-cli](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/):

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].[InstanceId]' --filters Name=instance-state-name,Values=running --output text
```

Comment: you call that easy? :D I'm sure the designers had good intentions.

Answer (score 22):

Expanding on John Rotenstein's answer you can definitely do this with describe-instances.

This will list Name tag and IP of all running instances whose Name tag contains a specific word:

```
name_tag=mongodb
aws ec2 describe-instances --filter "Name=tag-key,Values=Name" "Name=tag-value,Values=*$name_tag*" "Name=instance-state-name,Values=running" --query "Reservations[*].Instances[*][Tags[?Key=='Name'].Value[],NetworkInterfaces[0].PrivateIpAddresses[0].PrivateIpAddress]" --output text
```

Output:

```
10.100.2.10
mongodb0
10.100.2.11
mongodb1
10.100.2.12
mongodb2
```

A bonus here is that leaving name_tag empty lists **all** running instances.